# Why are comments not a node content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, comments

So Drupal has a 'special' commenting system.

> Comments are second-class citizens in Drupal compared to nodes...

But why did the core team not just create a default Content Type, Block and View for comments, and allow the site administrator add in a comment block as necessary? Just like the 'Article' and 'Basic Page' content types, which we can create blocks and views for. Why are comments so different?

Comment: You seem to be essentially asking "why are comments not nodes?" The answer is simply "because they're not supposed to do the same thing". Just like you wouldn't use a tractor to race in Grand Prix; it could theoretically be done, but it would be crazy to do so. Read [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22586/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-an-entity-versus-just-adding-a-new-content-type/22587#22587) for some more general background on entity types v content types

Comment: That IS essentially what I am asking. Thanks for the link, it is relevant. I would have asked a better question if I knew the terminology. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't trying to insinuate your question wasn't a good one - far from it in fact, if you're new to Drupal these sorts of things can be very confusing. I just wanted to get straight to the point though, in the case of comments v nodes it's as straightforward as "different requirements, different entity types"

Comment: @dayuloli now you know the terminology, so you can edit and **make** it a better question! :)

Comment: @Clive & Molot I'll read the link as well as more of the docs. And then I will edit the question. Thanks for taking the extra step to make sure I feel welcomed! Much appreciated! (I might come back with more questions later!)

Comment: Please avoid "Update" and alike in questions. Try to make them read as a natural whole. It shouldn't be hard to do it with this one. You have my upvote, but it does not mean I'll stop nagging you to make it a perfect question ;)

Comment: This question has technically been [asked before](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/22586/18794), but for anyone new to Drupal (like I am), they might not have the correct terminology to ask the right question. And so I am leaving this question as is.

Comment: @Mołot moved my 'update' into the comments, where it belongs? (:

Comment: @dayuloli comment or integral part of question, whatever you wish, just avoid parts that look so separate, if possible :)

Comment: The main reason for not making comments more like nodes is because they don't have to have a URL. You could try disabling the module "comments" and create your own comments content type with the assistance of other modules such as entity relationships, but when you do that you will later find yourself struggling and using some configuration tricks to hide their URL from search engines and users. A comment by itself is irrelevant, they have to be"attached" to something in order to make sense. Imagine a user finding a page of your website that says "I love it".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer this, I first had to understand one thing: ***Entities are not nodes***.

**Entity Types** are special groupings of fields.

**Node** is an entity type, which *requires* some fields, such as 'Title', 'Author' and 'Publish Date'.

**Content Types** are instances of Node which further define more fields. So a 'blog post' content type can have 'Hook', 'Introduction', 'Summary' and 'Related posts' fields, in addition to 'Title', 'Author' and 'Publish Date'.

Node is an entity type specialized for content. A comment is not designed to be a node because it is too different from a typical content. It's not necessary to have a 'Title', 'Author' or 'Publish Date' field in a comment. Because it is so different, it is created as another *Entity type* instead.

For more details, see this article on [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744).

Comment: Nodes, comments, taxonomy terms, users, etc are all entity types. Some have bundles, some don't. A node type is technically a "bundle" from entity point of view.

Comment: No need to dig very deeply to find something explicit: https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744

Comment: _Technically_ all entity types have a bundle @AyeshK. If one isn't provided core uses an implicit one

Comment: Thanks @clive - I actually meant some entity types have different bundles and some don't. Flag, Node are entity types with multiple bundle support. User, taxonomy term, etc have only one bundle. Thanks again for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 nodes and comments (and custom blocks and user added menu links and users and taxonomy terms and...) are entities both. While in D7 an entity was indeed just for a bundle of fields -- I still remember when they were simply `$object` and there was no API at all. In Drupal 8 entities have a proper CRUD API; they are classed objects with save, load etc. And comment settings are now a field so everything fieldable is commentable. The mind boggles at the possibilities (commented comments? Commentception! even that is possible AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Just as a sidenote, sometimes perhaps you really do not need the power of the core Comments entity, but just a simple list of comments or notes (without replies) associated to the Content Type or Entity.

In these cases, you may lighten your system load disabling the Comments for that Content Type, and using just a field for storing the comments or notes.

At least 2 contrib modules provide this kind of field:

- Field Comments: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_comments
- Comment Field: https://www.drupal.org/project/commentfield