# How to choose between node or entities

Tags: 7, entities

I hope this question is in the spirit of Q&A.

I have to develop a module that manages complex datasets in Drupal and I have to decide if it is better to use Nodes or Entities to manage all the necessary stuff (there are pros and cons for any case).

I undestand the different concepts behind (what an entity is, and the relation between the concepts of node and entities), so my question is: **when is better to use the former or the latter?**

I don't know what: there is a guide, an intereseting experience, a checklist, or something else to allow developers to perform the rigth choice when starting the development? What a Node can do that is impossible to have with an Entity (and in the case is necessary to re-develop in the case)?

Thank you

Comment: The duplicate is the general nodes v entities for D7, there's also this for D8 if you're interested: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197669/with-current-d8-status-whats-the-decision-tree-for-creating-a-new-content-enti?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Starting from your link I have been able to found a lot of interesting references to achieve a good opinion about. Thank you.